# Python, Tkinter: Making a grid of Checkboxes using Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, checkbox, tkinter

I'm trying to make a tkinter program that has a 3x3 grid of checkboxes, the code I have created to do this is:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,* args,** qwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.strCategories=("Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O")
        self.varCategories={}
        for x in self.strCategories:
            self.varCategories[x] = tk.IntVar()

        self.chckbxCategories={}
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                var = self.varCategories[self.strCategories[i*3+j]]
                x=10/40 + 11*i/40
                y=7/20 + 4*j/20
                print(str(x),str(y))

                checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=self.strCategories[i*3+j], font=('Lucida Grande',15),
                                          anchor='w', bg='#FFFFFF', variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
                checkbox.place(relx=x, rely=y, relwidth=10/40, relheight=5/20)
                self.chckbxCategories[self.strCategories[i*3+j]] = checkbox


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

However, the widgets don't appear on the screen! If I replace the `.place` with some other geometry manager it works (I'd like to use `.place` because its `relx` and `rely` handle resizing the screen for me) so I know the problem is not with making the widgets but with placing them.

What am I doing wrong?

Shell output:

```
0.25 0.35
0.25 0.55
0.25 0.75
0.525 0.35
0.525 0.55
0.525 0.75
0.8 0.35
0.8 0.55
0.8 0.75
```

Comment: maybe use 2-dimensional list/tuple `self.strCategories  = [ ["Q","W","E"] , ["R","T","Y"] , ["U","I","O"] ]` and then you will no need `range(3)`

Comment: it will be more readable `cb = tk.Checkbutton()` and `cb.place()` and `self.chckbxCategories[...] = cb`

Comment: do you use Python 2 ? Then `10/40` gives `0`, not `0.25`. Better use `print` to check values which you assign to `relx`, `rely`, etc.

Comment: I think the problem is that in `place(relx=10/4 + 11*i/4, ...)`, relx is here greater than one, so it's outside the window.

Comment: don't put so much code in one line. Use temporary variables. For example, calculate the relx and rely values and store the values in variables.. That will make it possible for you to examine the values to see if they are what you expect they are (they probably aren't).

Comment: @j_4321 I made a mistake there, should be 40 not 4

Comment: @furas No, I use Python 3.4/3.5

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried it out with print statements and found that it should be `relx=10/40 + 11*i/40` not `relx=10/4 + 11*i/4` but otherwise all value were as they should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reason that the widgets don't appear on screen is because they are in a frame, and you never added the frame to the main window. You need to call `pack`, `place` or `grid` on the instance of `App`.

Unrelated to the problem but related to good coding practices, you should explicitly create the root window. Change the last few lines of your code to look like this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
app.mainloop()
```

When you do this, you will now notice that your window shrinks to just a few pixels. This is because `place` does not cause the containing window to expand to fit its children. This is documented behavior, and is one of several reasons why `place` is not usually a good choice for doing widget layout. If you are creating a grid of widgets, `grid` is the natural choice, and it can easily be made to react properly when the window resizes.

That being said, to see your widgets when using `place` you need to force the containing frame or the main window to be large enough to fit this. You'll have to calculate this size, which is another reason why `place` isn't the optimal choice.

Once you've calculated a size, you can use `geometry` on the root window to force it to be big enough:

```
root.geometry("200x200")
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `.grid(... , sticky='news')` with `columnconfigure(..., weight=1)` to get the same result (I hope because I couldn't run your code to see expected result).

I keep categories as 2-dimensional tuple so I can easily use `for` loops and `item` - without all this `i*3+j` and `self.strCategories[i*3+j]`.

I create `IntVar()` in the same loop. And I use temporary `var` and `cb` so it is more readable.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

str_categories = ( ("Q","W","E"), ("R","T","Y"), ("U","I","O") )

var_categories = {}
chckbx_categories = {}

for r, row in enumerate(str_categories):

    root.columnconfigure(r, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)

    for c, item in enumerate(row):
        var = tk.IntVar()

        cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                            font=('Lucida Grande',15), anchor='w', bg='#FFFFFF')
        cb.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='news')

        var_categories[item] = var
        chckbx_categories[item] = cb

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

**BTW:** if you rather need categories as normal tuple then you can use `range(3)` and `item = str_categories[r*3+c]` but rest is the same.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

str_categories = ("Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O")

var_categories = {}
chckbx_categories = {}

for r in range(3):

    root.columnconfigure(r, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)

    for c in range(3):
        item = str_categories[r*3+c]

        var = tk.IntVar()

        cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                            font=('Lucida Grande',15), anchor='w', bg='#FFFFFF')
        cb.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='news')

        var_categories[item] = var
        chckbx_categories[item] = cb

root.mainloop()
```

Or you can create `"iterator"`

```
iterator = iter(str_categories)
```

and then you can get `"next"` item with

```
item = next(iterator)
```

Full version:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

str_categories = ("Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O")

iterator = iter(str_categories)

var_categories = {}
chckbx_categories = {}

for r in range(3):

    root.columnconfigure(r, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)

    for c in range(3):
        item = next(iterator)

        var = tk.IntVar()

        cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                            font=('Lucida Grande',15), anchor='w', bg='#FFFFFF')
        cb.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='news')

        var_categories[item] = var
        chckbx_categories[item] = cb

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is ok but the point of my code is that there would be other stuff on the screen and I want these checkboxes to adjust with the screen width